# Get Value of Current Selector

Tags: jquery

I am selecting zero or more elements in jQuery using the following selector:

```
$("input[type=tel]")
```

I want to change the value of the particular DOM element that is being selected, so I tried to use:

```
$("input[type=tel]").val($(this).val().replace(/D/, ""));
```

But it strips out all of the text instead of just the non-digits which makes me assume that `$(this)` is referring to the element that is calling the code (in my case a form that is calling onSubmit).

**Update**

I did not want to use the $.each() method as suggested in the comments and I was able to find a solution by using an inline function as demonstrated here:

```
$('input[type="tel"]').val(function() {return $(this).val().replace(/\D/g, "");});
```

Comment: You might be looking for:
https://api.jquery.com/each/

Comment: I would rather not implement this in an $.each(), but if necessary then I will.

Comment: Just curious, but why didn't you just use `this.value.replace( ... )` instead of making a call to `$(this).val()`?

Comment: Don't put the solution in the question, post your own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a function argument. It gets called on each selected element, with the current value as its argument (so you don't need to call `$(this).val()`), and the returned value is used as the value.

```
$("input[type=tel]").val(function(oldval) {
    return oldval.replace(/\D/g, '');
});
```

Comment: This solution is not the same as OP's edit.  `'D'` should be the regular expression `/\D/` for consistency with the question. (`\D` is regular expression notation for a non-digit character).  I now it doesn't affect the real solution of using a closure, but it feels "off" with it changed to a literal "D".

Comment: I didn't notice that he'd changed `/D/` to `/\D/g` in his edit.

Comment: Thank you for the response, but why in the world do you keep editing my posts? It is very offputting.

Comment: I edited the post because you put the answer in the question, which is not appropriate. Then I undid it when I noticed that you'd also made a substantive change there.